# Identifying new lines and adding a tag after it

Tags: javascript

This is my js code

```js
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'a.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
    }
}
```

It reads data from a.txt which is located in the root of my website.
But the problem is it doesn't load.
Sample:
[Check my site](http://roshayon.mobie.in/userscontent.html)

Comment: It actuallly works in your web site :)

Comment: There are more than one paragraphs but it loads every data in a single paragraph. I mean the 'enter's are not working here. It is not creating new lines (\n).

Comment: Coz its a text string, check my answer in a minute

Comment: I mean the line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is line endings as you mention in the comments, its just about white space / word wrapping. You can use pre tags:

```js
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'a.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = '<pre>' + reader.responseText + '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ain't working. There are line breaks in the main text file.

Comment: I replaced your div with pre from chrome inspector in your site, and it worked correct. What is not working ?

Comment: Main text is:`
 ১. মনোযোগ তৈরি করা :

২. মেডিটেশন করে নিন : `
And the output is:
`১. মনোযোগ তৈরি করা :২. মেডিটেশন করে নিন :`

Comment: Looks same here

Comment: The line breaks that are in the text file are not showing in the output.

Comment: Working. Thanks. <3

Comment: Thank you so much.